# Rescaling an asymptotic expansion

Tags: calculus

Is this correct? I am not convinced.

Rescale using $x=\varepsilon X$ with $X=O(1)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$ and give an asymptotic expansion of $(x+\varepsilon)^{1/2}$ which is valid for $x\ll\varepsilon$.

$$(x+\varepsilon)^{1/2}\tag{1}$$

Substitute $x=\varepsilon X$ in $(1)$ gives:
$$
(\varepsilon X+\varepsilon)^{1/2}=\varepsilon^{1/2}(X+\varepsilon)^{1/2}
$$
Binomial expansion:

$$
\sim  \varepsilon^{1/2}\left(1+\frac{X}{2}-\frac{X^2}{8}+O( \varepsilon^3)\right) \tag{2}
$$
if $x=\varepsilon X$, $X=\frac{x}{\varepsilon}$, substitute in $(2)$ gives

$$
\varepsilon^{1/2}\left(1+\frac{x}{2\varepsilon}-\frac{x^2}{8\varepsilon^2}+O(\varepsilon^3)\right)
$$

which gives an asymptotic expansion which is valid for $x \ll \varepsilon$.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vItQm.png))

Thanks

Comment: a couple mistakes here, mainly $(\epsilon x + \epsilon)^{1/2} = \epsilon^{1/2} (x+1)^{1/2}$ and not sure how (2) derives from subtitution in (1)

Comment: Why it's wrong ? ,  substitute in 1  and apply binomial expansion

Comment: is it suppose to be ( epsilon ( 1+x))^1/2

Comment: Why is the last term in (2) $O\left(\epsilon^3\right)$ when you are expanding $(x+1)^{1/2}$? The function you are expanding has no dependence on $\epsilon$ whatsoever.

Comment: yes thanks, suppose to be related to x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we seek an asymptotic expansion of $(x+\epsilon)^{1/2}$ which is valid for $x \ll \epsilon$. Substitute $u\epsilon = x$ and apply the generalized Binomial Theorem to get
$$
\begin{split}
(u\epsilon + \epsilon)^{1/2}
 &= \epsilon^{1/2} (u+1)^{1/2} \\ 
 &= \epsilon^{1/2}
    \left(1 + \frac{u}{2} - \frac{u^2}{8} + \mathcal{O}\left(u^3\right) \right)
    \quad \text{from Binomial Theorem} \\
 &= \epsilon^{1/2}
    \left(1 + \frac{x}{2 \epsilon}
            - \frac{x^2}{8 \epsilon^2}
            + \mathcal{O}\left(\epsilon^{-3}\right) \right)
    \quad \text{from back-substitution} \\
 &= \epsilon^{1/2} + \frac{x}{2\epsilon^{1/2}}
            - \frac{x^2}{8\epsilon^{3/2}}
            + \mathcal{O}\left(\epsilon^{-5/2}\right)
\end{split}
$$

**Sanity Check:**

As expected, when $x = 0$, the RHS looks like $\epsilon^{1/2}$

Comment: you know here why did you substitute back u = x epsilon , while u = x/epsilon

Comment: @FK thanks, careless mistake, corrected

Comment: Thank you for your help